# How to send ACK/NACK to server

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming

Below is client and server program that I wrote. Now I am confused how to send ack/nack in my program.
I saw few answers on stackoverflow but i am still confused. Can you give an example of ACK/NACK in TCP protocol using java

*Client*:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 2222);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean a = true;
        while (a) {

            //receving
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
            if (input.equals("q")) {
                a = false;
                client.close();
            }

            pw.println("Client0: " + input.nextLine());
            System.out.println(pw);
            // System.out.println("Request sent successfully");


        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

}

*Server*:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2222);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client request");
            Socket client = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection request");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {

                // receving
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String str = br.readLine();

                // sending
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
                ps.println("Server1: " + input.nextLine());
                System.out.println(ps);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: thank you @Mahek to edit my question.

Comment: define ACK/NACK. using socket streams you dont deal with TCP packets directly. if your program is sending and receiving lines correctly there's not much more you need to do, other the implement the logic of what your program is going to do when it sends and receives data.

Comment: note: you should set up the reader and writer / printstream objects OUTSIDE of the while loops. there is no need to recreate them. you'll only get problems recreating them.

Comment: @SlipperySeal  Ok I create them out of loop . But can you tell me how I can create ACK/NACK in my program.

Comment: you dont send TCP ACK NACKs using java code. the operating system handles all of that. all you need to do is write a line from your client and read it from the server. then respond. it looks like your code is going to do this already. what are you trying to achieve that it isn't doing now?

Comment: dont forget to use the flush() method on the writers after you have written your line.

Comment: network protocols use agreed message formats so that the other side knows when to stop reading and all the data has arrived. for example HTTP sends a bunch of lines and then two carriage returns and line feeds in a row to mean "i'm done". you can create your own simple protocol simply by writing a line (with an end of line), using println - and then you can respond with a line. you can make it more complex than that but its a good place to start

Comment: @SlipperySeal My program is working perfectly. But the thing is how I can send my ack to receive packets. I don't know how I can send packets and design a packet to receive and send ack/nack of my packet. I want to learn how to send ack/nack?  how to design packet? how to set a timer for my packet?  this is my ambition today.  :)

Comment: in that case you need to start writing code in C :). Java abstracts socket communications away using streams. You can't access the structures of the packets, create your own etc.  You can send UDP packets in Java but that's about it.

Comment: Well that is not a good idea to write in C. I want to learn in java. :(

Comment: you might be able to find a library which lets you do it. but you cant do this with the java standard library.

Comment: I didn't get my answer yet! :(

Comment: stack overflow is for helping with specific coding problems. if there were java methods for doing TCP ACK NACKs we would tell you what they are. but as there are not, you are going to need to find a third party library which suits exactly what you are trying to achieve. this is not what stack overflow is for. also your question of "how to send ACK NACKs in java" is too broad. you need to be more specific, such as "i want to do packet filtering" or "i want to implement my own TCP stack". not just "i want to send ACK NACK in java"